# Django: How to use data from a function as a field in Meta class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've created a function in my `serializers.py` that call an external API and give me a dict back.
How can I use the output from `return downloads` in the `get_all_files` as a field in `class Meta`?

After the first answer, I've got the following error message:

```
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable 
Exception Location: /app/api/serializers.py, line 68, in get_all_files
```

Line 68 is the following: `return get_all_files(instance.bands)`

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import views
from api.models import Application, Indice, Satellite, Band
from satsearch import Search

class IndiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Indice
        fields = ['name', 'accr', 'description', 'is_NormalizedDifference', 'calc', ]

class SatelliteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Satellite
        fields = ['name', 'accr', 'operator', ]

class BandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Band
        fields = ['band', 'description', 'wavelength', 'resolution', ]

class OsdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bands = BandSerializer(source='indice_to_use.needed_bands', many=True)
    satellite = SatelliteSerializer(source='indice_to_use.satellite_to_use')
    indice = IndiceSerializer(source='indice_to_use')
    files = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_files(self, instance):
        def get_all_files(bands):
            # configuration
            url = 'https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0' # URL to Sentinel 2 AWS catalog
            collection = 'sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs'

            # search parameter
            startDate = '2021-04-10'
            endDate = '2021-04-12'
            location = [ 13.6677,
                    43.7232,
                    16.2605,
                    45.4522
                ]

            bbox_search = Search(
                bbox=location, 
                datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate, 
                query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
                collections=[collection],
                url=url,
                sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
            )

            items = bbox_search.items()
            
            downloads = {}
            
            for i, item in enumerate(items):
                
                data = {}
                
                data['Product ID']= item.properties["sentinel:product_id"]
                data['Preview']= item.asset("thumbnail")["href"]
                data['Date']= item.properties["datetime"]
                data['Cloud cover']= item.properties["eo:cloud_cover"]
                
                for band in bands.split(','):
                    data[band] = item.asset(band)["href"]
                
                downloads[i] = data
                                    
            return downloads

        return get_all_files(instance.bands)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ['machine_name', 'name', 'description', 'indice', 'satellite', 'bands', 'files', ]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the import statement for the `Search` object.  Also, can you add a comment to the *exact* line the error is thrown?  Your example code is not even 68 lines long, so we have no way of knowing exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: Your're right. I've updated my question with your requested details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. The error was caused by a mistake in my backend. The key of the sat-search result was in 3 digest, e.g. `B03`. The content in my field was in two digst, e.g. `B3`. That's why the matching doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you would need to do the following:

Alongside the other serializers (bands, satellite and indices)

You should put:

```
files = SerializerMethodField()
```

This `SerializerMethodField` gets the value by calling the method `get_{field_name}`, in this case would be `get_files`. [More on this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

So you could move all the logic you have up there in this method:

```
def get_files(self, instance):

   return get_all_fields(instance.bands)
```

And now you would only have to put `files` in the `fields` list like this:

```
fields = ['machine_name', 'name', 'description', 'indice', 'satellite', 'bands', 'files']
```

Comment: Thanks Ariel, that helps. But now I get an error:

Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: /app/api/serializers.py, line 68, in get_all_files

Comment: That may be because you are not passing the `bands` field, or is not created within the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested function is throwing off the interpreter, which results in an incomplete stack trace.  I'd start by converting your `get_files` method to a more typical function:

```
class OsdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bands = BandSerializer(source='indice_to_use.needed_bands', many=True)
    satellite = SatelliteSerializer(source='indice_to_use.satellite_to_use')
    indice = IndiceSerializer(source='indice_to_use')
    files = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_files(self, instance):
        bands = instance.bands
        # configuration
        url = 'https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0' # URL to Sentinel 2 AWS catalog
        collection = 'sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs'

        # search parameter
        startDate = '2021-04-10'
        endDate = '2021-04-12'
        location = [ 13.6677,
                43.7232,
                16.2605,
                45.4522
            ]

        bbox_search = Search(
            bbox=location,
            datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate,
            query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
            collections=[collection],
            url=url,
            sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
        )

        items = bbox_search.items()

        downloads = {}

        for i, item in enumerate(items):

            data = {}

            data['Product ID']= item.properties["sentinel:product_id"]
            data['Preview']= item.asset("thumbnail")["href"]
            data['Date']= item.properties["datetime"]
            data['Cloud cover']= item.properties["eo:cloud_cover"]

            for band in bands.split(','):
                data[band] = item.asset(band)["href"]

            downloads[i] = data

        return downloads
```

Now when you run it, you will still get the `TypeError`, but it will point to the line where the error is actually occuring, which I assume is in the `downloads` loop.

If my assumption is correct, then you will need to make sure you are parsing the data correctly, because you are trying to access a key on an object that doesn't exist.  For example, in the line:

```
data['Preview']= item.asset("thumbnail")["href"]
```

if `item.asset('thumbnail')` returns `None`, then you would get this error.

If you still can't figure it out, please provide a link to the `satsearch` package, and/or show example data that is returned from `Search(...)`